# Position of button changes when caption is too long

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I currently work on a quiz app. There is a question and four possible answer options. Each answer options is represented by a button. The four buttons are aligned in a rectangle.

**Problem:** If the button caption is too long, the button position slightly changes NS the button slips downward.

**Question:** Is there is a solution for this problem? I dont want the button to change its position.

**XML Code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_voc_trainer_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is my title!"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_voc_trainer_first_answer_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_voc_trainer_question"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_first_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Answer 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_second_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Answer 2 is very long!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_voc_trainer_second_answer_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_voc_trainer_first_answer_row"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_third_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Answer 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_fourth_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Answer 4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_trainer_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_voc_trainer_second_answer_row"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="answer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This screenshot illustrates the problem. Button 2 has a longer caption and therefore his position automatically changed.

[image: Position of second button in first row changed due to caption]

Comment: Try ImageButton instead of Button

Comment: i think this question has been asked before....try to search it and find answer from it..

Comment: @null,but at my end 2nd button is not like other's after using android:baselineAligned="false" . is it OK with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this in your linear layout:

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_voc_trainer_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is my title!"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_voc_trainer_first_answer_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_first_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Answer 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_second_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Answer 2 is very long!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_voc_trainer_second_answer_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_third_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Answer 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_fourth_answer_possibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Answer 4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_trainer_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="answer" />

</LinearLayout>
```